# Why my layout not fill well on small screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-button, android-textinputlayout

I don't know why buttons not shrinking according to the screen size, given I used `ConstraintLayout`. Whenever I use screen size of 4" it not fits well. Also with update of `appcompat:1.1.0`, `TextInputLayout` got extra padding. I don't know how to fix it.
Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_formula_bar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_copy"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/tiet_formula_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:maxLength="40"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="11dp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_full_formula"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_memory"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_copy"
        style="@style/myIconButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cornerRadius="0dp"
        app:icon="?attr/actionModeCopyDrawable"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/til_formula_bar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/til_formula_bar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/til_formula_bar" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        app:hintEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b_save_hisab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_formula_bar">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/tiet_hisab_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:hint="@string/details"
            android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine|textAutoComplete"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_save_hisab"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/save"
        app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b_date"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:insetLeft="6dp"
        android:insetRight="6dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ctl_calcy"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_picture"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b_save_hisab" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_picture"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:insetLeft="6dp"
        android:insetRight="6dp"
        android:text="@string/attachments"
        app:icon="@android:drawable/stat_notify_more"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_date"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_date"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/ctl_calcy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b_date"
        tools:visibility="invisible">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_mem_minus_equals"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/symbol__mem_minus_equals"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_mem_add_equals"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_mem_recall"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_mem_add_equals" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_eight"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/digit_zero"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_seven"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_nine"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_seven" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_three"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/digit_three"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_two"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_plus"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_two" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_nine"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/digit_nine"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_eight"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_multiply"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_eight" />

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/b_percentage"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/symbol_percent"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_zero"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_divide"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_zero" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_clear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/symbol_clear"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b_mem_clear"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ib_backspace"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_minus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/symbol_minus"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_six"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_six" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_mem_clear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/symbol_meme_clear"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b_one"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_mem_add_equals"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b_clear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_divide"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/symbol_divide"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_percentage"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_percentage" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_five"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/digit_five"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_four"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_six"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_four" />

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/b_plus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/symbol_plus"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_three"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_three" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ib_backspace"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/backspace"
            app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_clear"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_clear"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_multiply"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/symbol_multiply"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_nine"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_nine" />

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/b_decimal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/symbol_decimal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_zero"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b_seven" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_one"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/digit_one"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b_four"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_two"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b_mem_clear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_four"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/digit_four"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b_seven"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_five"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b_one" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_zero"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/digit_zero"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_decimal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_percentage"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_decimal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_two"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/digit_two"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_one"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_three"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_one" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_mem_add_equals"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/symbol_mem_plus_equals"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_mem_clear"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_mem_minus_equals"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_mem_clear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_mem_recall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/symbol_mem_recall"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_mem_minus_equals"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_mem_minus_equals" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_seven"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/digit_seven"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b_decimal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_eight"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b_four" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_six"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetLeft="6dp"
            android:insetRight="6dp"
            android:text="@string/digit_six"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b_five"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_minus"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_five" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Layout Screen]

**Layout Screen**

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
And:

with this:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1"
```

Do it for every button.

`wrap_content` means that your button will take height according to its own height (it not responsive).

While using
`app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"` 
`app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1"`

your buttons will be 10% both in with and height according to the screen size, and now just change the numbers and it will remain responsive.

Comment: what do you mean by that - is it not responsive? is it not compiling?

Comment: when I made those changes my layout distorted totally. I wonder how can I show changes.

Comment: And did you change  `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"`  to something smaller like 0.005

Comment: no I changed code exactly as you said -> Made those changes in all button widgets.

Comment: so what you have done is this - every button is 10% in height according to the screen, give the buttons a little smaller numbers and play with it

Answer (score 0):

Try this for "Attachments" button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_picture"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:insetLeft="6dp"
    android:insetRight="6dp"
    android:text="@string/attachments"
    app:icon="@android:drawable/stat_notify_more"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/b_date"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/b_date"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_date"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
```

For TextInputLayout,
You can remove extra space above AppCompatEditText by setting app:hintEnabled="false", but it won't display hint until you re-enable that.